# I have no idea whatsever why my question was closed as too-story based, it was pure worldbuilding. I request to reopen it!

Tags: support, reopening-questions

[What is the reason behind the iron law of necromancy, "In order to raise the dead you must be dead yourself"?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/207782/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-iron-law-of-necromancy-in-order-to-raise-the-dea)

"You are asking questions about a story set in a world instead of about building a world."

This [situation] is just crazy.

Comment: Calling other users crazy is not the best way to get any question reopened. Tune down the self-entitlement, thanks

Comment: @L.Dutch I don't call other users crazy, I say that the situation is crazy. I would also appreciate if you either reopened the question or explained why it must stay closed in its current form.

Comment: I would have closed it for opinions instead of story-based, as it is stated as of now. Check sphennings comment, sums up quite well. That doesn't change much to the outcome, though :p.

Comment: @Tortliena Isn't it double standards? All questions that lack tag "hard-science" can be closed for the same reason.

Comment: @user161005 I'm writing a full answer to get you a better understanding. Just wait a little :).

Comment: @Tortliena Ok, I will wait for your answer!

Answer (score 3):

**REQUEST GRANTED!!!**
...All you have to do is edit your question slightly! I have no horse (or dog) in this race, but I can tell you that I would not have voted to close your question because of it being story based. As you say, there's no story here -- no elements of plot formation or character development. It is however an opinion based query. I generally don't vote to close queries that others find to be opinion based, simply because 90% of the questions in the forum would have to be closed and WB.SE would have to be shut down.

We deal in opinions on a daily basis.

However, you placed no or insufficient restrictions on the answers. By this I mean you did not provide any criteria by which you'd adjudicate an answer as "best". How should we distinguish one excellent answer from the next? Every single answer is as valid as the next, so it's up to you to delineate exactly what you're looking for in an answer.

Comment: Okay,  I edited it. I tried to close "loopholes" and clear some unclear details that I found in answers of other users. Check it out, is it good enough?

Comment: I tried to make the question more restrictive by providing more details about the world.

Comment: @user161005 -- Sorry I wasn't there for the grand reopening! Anyway, it's clear you've done a good job at reinventing a good but poorly fashioned query! I look forward to seeing more of your worlding in the future!

Answer (score 0):

As you [said in comments](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/207782/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-iron-law-of-necromancy-in-order-to-raise-the-dea?noredirect=1#comment643709_207782), you posted the question to share your worldbuilding.

Per the [help centre](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic):

> When asking questions keep in mind that the goal of the site is to help you build your world, **not to tell your story.**

You are correct that answering your own question is allowed and encouraged (I've done it myself), but the question can't be about your story, and questions in general need to be answerable such that one answer is more correct than others (the so-called best answer restriction). As it stands your question is rather open-ended and has produced numerous answers all equally and conceivably valid. Your posted answer of stretched souls isn't clearly a better answer than being required to petition the undeath in person, even if it's the reason you chose for your story.

Comment: "but the question can't be about your story" But I have no "my story" in the first place! Initially I just exercised in worldbuilding, without attempt to tell a story.  "all equally and conceivably valid" Not all, see my comments to answers of "user535733" and "Corey".

Comment: I basically came up with a worldbuilding problem **and** my solution to said problems and shared both of them. Such behaviour is encouraged on stackexchange sites.

Comment: Sorry to say that, but there's an option to say specifically it is opinion-based, which fits a lot more your point. Why did you choose story-based instead of "requesting for opinions", if you did chose that option?

Comment: @Tortliena While people often VTC for multiple reasons, only one reason is displayed once the question is closed. You have no way of knowing what reason Rek selected when they cast the final vote.

Comment: @sphennings That's why I don't omit the possibility that they choose another motive of closure, even though it'd be weird to come back presenting arguments for a story-based one ^^.

Comment: @Tortliena I believe I voted that it was inappropriate for wb.SE, for the stated reason of wanting to share someone's worldbuilding rather than asking a question, and I think those both get the same closure notice. But it was also clearly too open-ended and would generate an infinite list of valid answers.