# I request to open my question again or explain why it's worse than 90% of other questions here

Tags: support, reopening-questions

[What is the reason behind the First Iron Law of necromancy, "In order to raise the dead you must be dead yourself"?](https://worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/questions/207782/what-is-the-reason-behind-the-first-iron-law-of-necromancy-in-order-to-raise-t)

Private feedback: "This question does not appear to be about worldbuilding"

Just... How? This reason is total bonkers. I just can't understand how it's **not** about worldbuilding. Am I missing something?

> "I’m voting to close this question because there is no objective way
> to determine the suitability of an answer. – Monty Wild♦"

My dear friend, then why do you not vote to close all other questions that lack tag "hard science"? Looks like double standards.

Comment: The closing reason is not "not about worldbuilding"

Comment: @L.Dutch Then why is it stated this way in the private feedback?

Comment: I can't read the private feedback you are quoting. I can read what you posted above, which states " because there is no objective way to determine the suitability of an answer."

Comment: @L.Dutch Any ideas why it was stated such in the private feedback? Who chooses what to put in the private feedback? How does the private feedback work?

Comment: I don't know what is happening here (apart from the fact you recreated your question and lost my in-progress answer), but I guess there's a ["friendlier" duplicate here](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8381/why-was-this-question-unsuitable-for-this-site) with already a clean answer from JBH :). @user161005 Remember that texts online are easily misinterpreted, so the way you are asking your question -while legitimate- would show to many a lot more "irritation" than I'd bet you actually have ^^'. This way is not the best mood to get a good answer

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Why was this question "unsuitable for this site"](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8381/why-was-this-question-unsuitable-for-this-site)

Comment: @Tortliena I'm at a point when I'm so frustrated that I don't delete my question only because there is one person who bookmarked it.

Comment: @Tortliena I tried to improve it, but now I'm out of ideas.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [I have no idea whatsever why my question was closed as too-story based, it was pure worldbuilding. I request to reopen it!](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8375/i-have-no-idea-whatsever-why-my-question-was-closed-as-too-story-based-it-was-p)

Comment: I once [asked a question on SO for the purpose of answering it](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45524214/4526528). It was closed by the Mods - and they were mad at me because they didn't want a roll-up question, they wanted people to use SE the way it's meant to be used and chase through the duplicate chains. It's a fairly popular question that's been appreciated by a lot of people. Am I angry about it? No, irritated, but not angry. And I don't care if it's ever reopened - because the worth of my soul isn't tied to it and the purpose for writing it remains intact. So, what's the real problem here?

Answer (score 3):

**I'm Confused**
Didn't you ask this question the other day? [I remember answering you!](https://worldbuilding.meta.stackexchange.com/a/8377/37029)

I think, just perhaps, you didn't follow through on the bit where I suggested that you place restrictions on the answers. Your question is fine, but a lot of good questions get closed (for being opinion based) simply because the OP doesn't list any criteria for determining which answer best fits the question.

Basically, consider editing a short section at the end that says "these are the criteria that a good answer will have" and then list what it is you're looking for. Just asking for help to explain is like asking for an infinite list of things, when what we need here is much shorter finite list!

Comment: I placed restrictions, but it turned out not to be enough and question got closed, again.

Comment: @user161005 I don't think it was opened then reclosed again :/ ? In any case, the question is 4 out of 5 votes to be reopened ;).

Comment: @Tortliena I can assure you that it was! I got notification that it was openned and then I also got notification that it was closed again!